# RubyGems is installing redis and daemons gems during 'gem install <other>', but they're not dependencies

Tags: rubygems, dependencies

I am using RubyGems 2.0.2.

When I install a gem that does not seem to have a dependency to redis nor daemons, it installs them.

```
% gem install my_gem 
Successfully installed my_gem-0.1.2
Fetching: daemons-1.1.9.gem (100%)
Successfully installed daemons-1.1.9
Fetching: redis-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed redis-3.0.4
Parsing documentation for my_gem-0.1.2
Installing ri documentation for my_gem-0.1.2
Parsing documentation for daemons-1.1.9
Installing ri documentation for daemons-1.1.9
Parsing documentation for redis-3.0.4
Installing ri documentation for redis-3.0.4
Done installing documentation for my_gem, daemons, redis after 3 seconds
3 gems installed
```

Here's what I did to check gem dependency.

```
% foreach i ( `gem list | sed -e 's/\ .*//' ` )
foreach? echo $i
foreach? gem dependency $i | grep "redis\|daemons"
foreach? end
```

None of my installed gems has a dependency to redis or daemons. Where else could RubyGems be getting dependency info from?